# Setting up an endpoint in an Always-On task

Tags: pythonanywhere

I am currently having an issue with running a web server and a Discord bot asynchronously as an Always-On task.

On my local machine, I would use ngrok to expose my local host to receive the payloads from webhooks to be processed by my web server that is run using aiohttp, which would then have the Discord bot do different things based on the the content in the payload.

I am now looking to host this on PythonAnywhere, but am struggling to figure out how I could configure an endpoint without using ngrok. The web app on PythonAnywhere does not seem to be able to help me since it apparently does not support async.

Any help would be really useful for I have been going at it for days and still couldn't figure out a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't expose a websocket on PythonAnywhere. If the payload is sent via http, you could use a web app which would listen and than communicate this to Always-on task which could be processing asynchronuously, as async works in Always-on tasks.

Comment: @caseneuve Does PythonAnywhere's web app allow me to do this? And if yes, is there any documentation on how I can do this? Thanks for the initial response by the way!

Comment: This help page is probably a good starting point: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AsyncInWebApps